# How the grammar of this sentence works?

Tags: grammar, translation

The sentence in question is the second line of:

> いつもここにいて欲しいくせに…
>   いつもここにいて欲しい心隠した
>   会えなくなったら淋しいの

I know that ここにいてほしい is I want you to be here but the second part is tricky to me

> 心かくした

Sounds strange to me it could mean something like "Hide my heart", how can you link that second part in to the first one to have any sense. Also is that grammatically correct? (I'm only N4 so I've never seen anything like it)

Comment: More context? Are you 100% sure you reported the entire sentence correctly? For example there is no "を" after かくす,  is かくす written in hiragana etc.

Comment: Yes, I was asked about this and I couldn't understand that second part. I search a little and I found that is part of a song called "I Call Your Name Again - Aoyama Nanami". Here you have a segment of the song: いつもここにいて欲しいくせに…
いつもここにいて欲しい心隠した
会えなくなったら淋しいの

Comment: Obviously I meant "を" after 心 ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you would have a  "を" after 心 and it is omitted for metric purposes of the song and/or because the register is informal.

> いつもここにいて欲しいくせに…
>   Even though I want you to be always here
>   いつもここにいて欲しい心隠した
>   I hid the heart that wishes so
>   会えなくなったら淋しいの
>   (and) I'm sad if I can't see you

So I guess it would be something like （私は）いつもここに居て欲しい心（を）隠した.

To recap, the point being "Even though I want you to be always here, I have hidden the heart (that part of me) that wishes so (... and now that I can't see you I'm sad)". This last one of course is not meant to be a literal translation.

Comment: @LuisFernandoBadelMéndez you're welcome. Although I'm quite sure what I said makes sense, I suggest you always wait a while before accepting the answer. Sometimes translations are subtle and maybe some native speaker could improve the answer if not in some cases even point out that is completely wrong (though hopefully this is not the case).